# How many times is 'love' mentioned in the Qur'an?

Tags: quran

I understand this may be a difficult question to answer linguistically, but I'm interested to hear any estimate along with an explanation of the methodology used to arrive at it.

Comment: it is one word answer hence belongs to list category question , hence voting to close.

Comment: It is not difficult question if you just want the wordcount occurrence then [this link](http://corpus.quran.com/search.jsp?q=love)
provides the answer.

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: @hellzone I read a claim that it is not mentioned often and the implication was that love is less important in the Qur'an. I have no way of knowing whether the claim was credible or not. Of course the answer doesn't prove anything but it is an interesting piece of the jigsaw.

Answer (score 1):

Many times.  Following are some examples of the Quran.

Allah loves the God-fearing people.
Allah loves those who favor other.
Allah loves those who are kind to others.
Allah does not love the disbelievers
Allah does not love the oppressors.
Say, if you love Allah, then follow me, then Allah will love you.
Those who believe love Allah more than anything else.....so many verses to go.....

Answer (score 1):

"Love" specifically, *without* counting loves, loved, or other variations, seems to be **mentioned 53 times** when searching using the [Quranic Arabic Corpus search tool](http://corpus.quran.com/search.jsp?q=love). Using [The world's most powerful digital tool for studying the Qur'an: its text, composition, and transmission](https://info.gateway.org), I **found 104 verses that contain "love."** These 104 verses *do include* variations of love, such as loved, loves, lover, etc. You will have to create an account to use info.gateway.org, the 2nd resource mentioned. It has access to a lot of other great resources.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different words that can be called "love."

The first word we can consider is حُبّ. It appears in this noun form [9 times](http://searchq.fussilat.com/?s=Hubb). Example:

> And [yet], among the people are those who take other than Allah as equals [to Him]. They love them similar to the(ir) **love** of Allah. [...] (2:165)

Derivatives of this word, on the other hand, appear [95 times](http://searchq.fussilat.com/?s=H,b,b). Example:

> [...] Indeed, Allah does not **love** the transgressors. (2:190)

Another word we can consider is مَوَدَّةً. It appears [8 times](http://searchq.fussilat.com/?s=mawaddaht) in this noun form. Example:

> And of His signs is that He created for you from yourselves mates that you may find tranquillity in them; and He placed between you **affection** and mercy. [...] (30:21)

Derivatives of this word from the root ود appear [29 times](http://searchq.fussilat.com/?s=w,d,d). Example:

> And ask forgiveness of your Lord and then repent to Him. Indeed, my Lord is Merciful and **Affectionate**." (11:90)

Mercy is the word in this topic that Islam highlights most, and it functions similar to the word "love".

The word رحمة‏ (mercy) appears in the Quran [116 times](http://searchq.fussilat.com/?s=:raH.maht%20;%20:raH.mat) in this noun form. Example:

> [...] My **mercy** encompasses all things [...] (7:156)

Derivatives of the word mercy appear an amazing [339 times](http://searchq.fussilat.com/?s=r,H,m) in the Quran. Example:

> In the name of Allah, the **Entirely Merciful**, the **Especially Merciful**. (1:1)